# Knockout with DataTables (editing modal, pagination, search and sorting)

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, datatables

I just started to learn knockout and I'm stuck. 
I need to load a data from server and show it with DataTables and each cell is binded with knockout.

- The table should have basic functions: Search, Sorting, Pagination.
- each item must have a Column with some actions like: Edit, Remove, Link.
- editing must be made in Modal Window

I found a similar example with almost all my needs and changed a little bit: http://jsfiddle.net/bq5f7fcc/11/

**This is custom KO binding:**

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach = {
page: 0,
init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
  var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
  ko.unwrap(options.data);
  if(options.dataTableOptions.paging){
    valueAccessor().data.subscribe(function (changes) {
        var table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page = table.page();
        table.destroy();
    }, null, 'arrayChange');          
  }
    var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(element.childNodes, 0);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(nodes, function (node) {
        if (node && node.nodeType !== 1) {
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);  
        }
    });
    return ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {        
    var options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()),
        key = 'DataTablesForEach_Initialized';
    ko.unwrap(options.data);
    var table;
    if(!options.dataTableOptions.paging){
      table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable();
        table.destroy();
    }
    ko.bindingHandlers.foreach.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    table = $(element).closest('table').DataTable(options.dataTableOptions);
    if (options.dataTableOptions.paging) {
       if (table.page.info().pages - ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page == 0) 
           table.page(--ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
       else 
           table.page(ko.bindingHandlers.dataTablesForEach.page).draw(false);                
    }        
    if (!ko.utils.domData.get(element, key) && (options.data || options.length))
        ko.utils.domData.set(element, key, true);
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
}
```

};

How can I add SEARCH field from DataTables?

P.S. Table will have a large amount of data (3-7k of rows).

Comment: To turn the searching back on, change `dom: 'rtip',` in the html configuration to `dom: 'frtip',` which turn on filtering.  However, the pagination is using knockout so the filter is restricted to just the items on the screen rather than the full data set.

Comment: ps - if you are using datatables 1.10+ the following may help you http://datatables.net/dev/knockout/

Comment: Take a look for this [plugin](http://jmvtrinidad.github.io/knockout-datagrid/). although there's no sorting for this one. It also has a class for ASP.NET Model binding.

Comment: @brianlmerritt Thank you! I changed to "frtip" and search field appeared. One more thing, search can't find the row if I edit it and the new name value is not updated in DataTables but visually it was updated. Is there any way to update table after row was edited? or can cause a performance issue?

Comment: Can somebody explain why the **urlDomains** function
`that.urlDomains = function(data) {
    return "/user?name=" + data.first;
};` is not generating the proper url ? 
here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bq5f7fcc/14/ (when I hover it returns a function...)